# Account Number Count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reaching out to see if there is a way to count the number of times an account number or other key shows up in a dataframe and then place that count in the row with the account number. I know there is the `value_counts()` function but that is not what I am wanting to do.

This is what I am wanting to achieve. The count column is what I am wanting to append to the dataframe:

```
    account    count  
0   456        3
1   123        4
2   258        2
3   456        3
4   123        4
5   123        4
6   258        2
7   456        3
8   123        4
```

Comment: have a look at [```pandas.transform```](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with either of the following.

```
df["count"] = df['account'].map(df['account'].value_counts())
#32ms on 1 million rows
```

```
df["count"] = df.groupby(['account'])['account'].transform('count')
#52ms on 1 million rows
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. That is exactly what i was looking for.